# Do I need root to flash a ROM onto a Samsung device?

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing

Just for my curiosity, do I need to have root on a Samsung device to flash a ROM onto it with Odin/Heimdall? My device is already rooted (by means of an exploit), but if this is true, one could root by flashing a custom ROM that is already rooted instead of using an exploit.

Comment: Now the reason I ask this question is that (I believe) HTC devices need S-OFF to flash a ROM (which is what a full root would include).